# Casting a java class to a generic kotlin class alters which function is called

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have the following kotlin classes:

```
abstract class Base<I> {
    open fun test(value: I)  {
        Log.i("Base", value.toString());
    }
}
abstract class SubClass : Base<Long>() {
    abstract override fun test(value: Long);
}
```

And a java class that inherits from them:

```
public class SubSubClass extends SubClass {
    @Override
    public void test(final long value) {
        Log.i("SubSubClass", value + "");
    }
}
```

Now the following code produces weird behavior

```
t.test(123)
(t as Base<Long>).test(123)

>I/SubSubClass: 123    
>I/Base: 123
```

while I would expect

```
>I/SubSubClass: 123
>I/SubSubClass: 123
```

What's going on here? And how can it be fixed? (Note: I can't really change the java class because it's generated by room)

Comment: It's because in Java, `long` is not a valid type parameter. Kotlin's `Long` is a bit of a weird hybrid, but I'm fairly certain compiled to `java.lang.Long`, and your `@Override test` isn't actually an override. I suggest using `javap` to list the actual signatures in the class files.

Comment: @efekctive when I use `123L` the behavior is the same

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- That seems to be the issue. When I use `java.lang.Long` as generic argument it works as intended.

Comment: SubClass has test as abstract. Base does not. SubSubClass is just going up the hierarchy

Comment: Can you show how you're compiling everything? This looks like a compiler bug somewhere in that either your `override` or your `@Override` should be failing. (I think it's probably the first one, actually, but am not certain.)

Comment: In these snippets, if they compile, an abstract subclass method that has a concrete implementation in the base makes no sense. Swap them or remove the one from subclass

Comment: I do not believe that JVM prohibits the search of concrete implementations fro

Comment: m going upstream.

Comment: create the same `SubSubClass` but in kotlin and use kotlin decompile and you will see that 2 methods are created, for `long` and `Long` (`this.test(((Number)var1).longValue());` in `Long` function), i think it's java-kotlin interop feature you should do the same

Comment: @IR42 I can't change the java class because it's generated by room